# window.getSelection() returns unexpected values

Tags: javascript

I'm using a div with `contenteditable` to make a text editor. I feel I have failed at one of the first hurdles.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="bold" value="B" />
<div id="wysiwyg" contenteditable="true" style="border:solid;width:500px;height:300px;"></div>

<script>
var bold = document.getElementById("bold");
var wysiwyg = document.getElementById("wysiwyg");

bold.addEventListener("click", function(){
    update("<b>", "</b>");
});    

function update(startTag, endTag){

//find the selected text
 var selected_text = "";
   if (window.getSelection) {
        selected_text = window.getSelection();
   } else if (document.getSelection) {
        selected_text = document.getSelection();
   } else if (document.selection) {
        selected_text = document.selection.createRange().text; 
   }

   //user could have selected in reverse, so we need to make sure the values are in correct order
var startPos = selected_text.anchorOffset >= selected_text.focusOffset ? selected_text.focusOffset : selected_text.anchorOffset;
var endPos = selected_text.focusOffset <= selected_text.anchorOffset ? selected_text.anchorOffset : selected_text.focusOffset;

if (startPos == endPos) //There is no selection
    return;

var startText = wysiwyg.innerText.substr(0, startPos);
var textToWrap = wysiwyg.innerText.substr(startPos, endPos- startPos);
var endText = wysiwyg.innerText.substr(endPos);
wysiwyg.innerHTML = startText + startTag + textToWrap + endTag + endText;

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you were to execute this code and type 3 words into the div, select the middle word (highlight with the mouse) then click the B button on the screen (in the HTML), you'd note the program executes as desired, in that it will make the word you highlighted bold.

If you now select the last word of the 3 you typed, and try to make it bold, you'll note the first word becomes bold.

A look at the code, I can see the issue is `selected_text.anchorOffset` initially returns the correct value, but on subsequent requests, it gets it wrong (or at least, provides a value I don't understand).

This [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b5yaows9/) will demonstrate the issue!

Why does window.getSelection return incorect selected text start and end positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to make it complicated. If you are supporting any browser from IE8 and above then you can use `execCommand` function. The updated code is below:

```
var bold = document.getElementById("bold");
var wysiwyg = document.getElementById("wysiwyg");

bold.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.execCommand('bold');
});
```

To add to the answer and if you haven't figured it out why your code didn't work.

Firstly, the definition from MDN for focusOffset or anchorOffset (both are similar):

"Selection.focusOffset : The Selection.focusOffset read-only property returns the number of characters that the selection's focus is offset within the **Selection.focusNode**."

Let's take an example of text: "Make text bold" and we're selecting "bold" each time.

The first time, It counts the position correctly and makes the element bold. So the new text looks like "`Make text <b>bold</b>`".

Second time, It counts the position from the `<b>` tag. So, its 0-3 and the text will be "`<b>Make<b/> text bold`".

Third time, It counts the position from the `</b>` tag. So, its 6-9 and result text will be "`Make t<b>ext </b>bold`".

Fourth time, It count the position from the `</b>` tag. So, its 0-3 again. So, 0-3 and 6-9 pattern will repeat again and again.

Comment: I hate this answer because I'd already created a full editor using textarea and a div to make a preview... And then I though I'd be clever and use `contenteditable` with a div... And the functionality is already built in. What a tricky 3 days of work! Regardless, the answer is perfect and my editor now works a lot more efficiently, without showing the source code! Thanks